# Display x amount left until discount - liquid

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopping-cart

I want to show a message how much client needs to spend more until he gets additional discount. I have 4 discounts setup in shopify discounts.
I achieved needed behaviour with liquid:

```
   {% assign discount1_threshold = 81 %}
   {% assign discount2_threshold = 61 %}
   {% assign discount3_threshold = 41 %}
   {% assign discount4_threshold = 20 %}

   {% if cart_total < discount4_threshold %}
    Amount until 5% discount {{ discount4_threshold | minus: cart_total }}€
   {% elsif cart_total < discount3_threshold %}
    Amount until 2% discount {{ discount3_threshold | minus: cart_total }}€
   {% elsif cart_total < discount2_threshold %}
    Amount until 3% discount {{ discount2_threshold | minus: cart_total }}€
   {% elsif cart_total < discount1_threshold %}
    Amount until 2% discount {{ discount1_threshold | minus: cart_total }}€
   {% else %}
    Congrats! You've reached maximum discount value.
   {% endif %}
```

However, it needs to be refreshed everytime you add to cart to update the message.

I've tried using JS but sadly couldn't make it work.